# Javax, @DefaultValues, @PrePersistent, @PreUpdate

Tags: java, java-ee

Estou aprendendo a mexer com Javax, e persistencia do Java e quero saber se há algum modo de deixar um valor default pro banco de dados.

Exemplo no SQL:

```
variacao TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Como faria isso no meu código Modelo ?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@NotNull
@Column(name="nota")
private int nota;

@NotNull
@Column(name="data")
private Timestamp data;

@Column(name="comentario")
private String comentario;

@Column(name="evento_id")
private Evento evento_id;

@Column(name="pessoa_id")
private Pessoa pessoa_id;
```

1) Qual diferença dos seguintes itens?
a) @DefaultValues
b) @PrePersistent
c) @PreUpdate

2) E qual eu usaria para este caso ?
a) @DefaultValues
b) @PrePersistent
c) @PreUpdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você está usando JPA, nesse caso caso prefira deixar o valor default ser gerado pelo banco utilize assim:

`@Column(name = "DATA_ATUALIZACAO", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")`

Isso só irá funcionar se você deixar o JPA criar as tabelas, ou exportar o script de criação das tabelas.

> 1) Qual diferença dos seguintes itens?
>
> @PrePersist

**Callback é executado antes da entidade ser persistida.**

> @PreUpdate

**Callback é executado antes da entidade ser atualizada.**

> 2) E qual eu usaria para este caso ?

Isso irá depender do objetivo da sua coluna, por exemplo:

- Se sua coluna **DATA** você para armazenar a **data de cadastro** teria que  usar `@PrePersist`;
- Se sua coluna **DATA** você para armazenar a **data de atualização** teria que  usar `@PreUpdate`;

Consulte em [hibernate] que é uma das implementações do JPA: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html

Comment: Para que serve o DefaultValue ? E tambem, pelo que vi o PrePersist e PreUpdate são métodos, correto ?

Comment: @FelipeJunges Sim, voce coloca `@PrePersist` e `@PreUpdate` em um metodo e dentro dele alteras os valores da entity como quiser. A anotaçao `DefaultValue` nao existe